# Decomposition of normal standard distribution with equicorrelation matrices

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, decomposition

Suppose $x_{ij}\sim N(0,1)$ such that $Cov(x_{ij},x_{il})=0$ for $j\neq l$,  $Cov(x_{ij},x_{kj})=\rho$ for $i\neq k$, and
$$[E[x_{ik}x_{jk}] ]_{ij} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho & \cdots & \rho\\
\rho & 1 & \cdots & \rho\\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\rho & \rho &\cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p},$$ for each $k$ and $\rho>0$. The data matrix is given by $X=[x_{ij}]_{p\times n}$.

I find a lemma as follows:

Suppose $\rho>0$. Then we can find random variables $\{\xi_j,\xi_{ij};\ 1\le i\le p,\ 1\le j\le n\}$ are i.i.d as N(0,1) such that $$x_{ij}=\sqrt{\rho}\xi_j+\sqrt{1-\rho}\xi_{ij}$$.

I am stuck to prove that lemma.

What are your thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: 1) linear combinations of iid normals are jointly normal. 2) so just calculate, pairwise, the correlations between your constructed variables $x_{ij}=\sqrt{\rho}\xi_j+\sqrt{1-\rho}\xi_{ij}$

Comment: Could you explain more detail? Actually I already try to define $\xi_j$ and $\xi_ij$ where $\xi_j= a \sum_{i=1}^p x_{ij}+ b\sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}$ and $\xi_{ij}=(x_{ij} -\sqrt{\rho}\xi_{j})/\sqrt{1-\rho}$ with  a and b are not zero. I stuck because I found that $\xi_i$ and $\xi_{ij}$ are not independent.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean $\xi_k$ and $\xi_l$ are not independent.

Comment: In your post you have stated they are independent! (that is what iid implies). So please then correct your post, by editing it, with the correct information.

Comment: I mean they are iid for each columns but not for rows. I already edited the post.

Comment: You could drop the second index for the sake of the simplicity. Then simply check that the covariance of the vector $\mathbf{X} = \sqrt{\rho} \eta \mathbf{1} + \sqrt{1 - \rho} \boldsymbol{\xi}$ is a wanted,  where $\eta$ and $\boldsymbol{\xi}$ are independent and $\boldsymbol{\xi}$ has independent elements.